# Sql data fetch query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, phpmyadmin

I am facing an issue when I use FUll join the same query when I use Left or right join query executed but when I replace with Full join occur error.

```
#Query
select employees.first_name,departments.department_name
  from employees
  FULL JOIN departments ON employees.department_id=departments.department_id
```

Error:

Error
SQL query: Copy Documentation

```
select employees.first_name,departments.department_name
  from employees
  FULL JOIN departments ON employees.department_id=departments.department_id 
 ORDER BY employee_id
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'employees.first_name' in 'field list'[image]

Comment: Oracle doesn't have LIMIT and MySQL doesn't have FULL join. What is your Exact DB? Which query is giving you error on which DB?

Comment: am using Xxamp for testing MySql db